# Postgres sorting order not respecting default C collation?

Tags: postgresql, collation, international-components-unicode

I have a postgres DB running in an AL2023 docker image:

```
postgres=# select version();
select version();
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 15.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 11.4.1 20230605 (Red Hat 11.4.1-2), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

I created this using these args:

```
--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=C.UTF8 --encoding=UTF8
```

Which produces the following:

```
The database cluster will be initialized with this locale configuration:
  provider:    icu
  ICU locale:  C.UTF8
  LC_COLLATE:  C
  LC_CTYPE:    C
  LC_MESSAGES: C
  LC_MONETARY: C
  LC_NUMERIC:  C
  LC_TIME:     C
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
```

If I ask for a sorting between caps and noncaps, I get lower case coming first which (a) isn't what I want and (b) isn't what I'd expect for ASCII / UTF-8 / C

```
postgres=# select 'C' < 'c';
select 'C' < 'c';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

So if I used the C collation, I'd get it the right way round, perhaps?

```
postgres=# select 'C' < 'c' collate "C";
select 'C' < 'c' collate "C";
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I thought I was using C, so I check what collation am I using and get ...

```
postgres=# select datname, datcollate from pg_database;
select datname, datcollate from pg_database;
  datname  | datcollate 
-----------+------------
 postgres  | C
 template1 | C
 template0 | C
(3 rows)
```

I'm using C - so why is the default not the same as if I use C explicitly?

Comment: Note that starting in v16, this fails with "could not convert locale name "C.UTF8" to language tag" so validation has improved since v15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C.UTF8` is not a valid ICU collation.  If you give ICU a garbage collation name like that, it ignores what it cannot parse, and you probably end up with the `und` collation instead. That would explain what you are seeing.

If you want the binary collation, do *not* use ICU collations, but the default C library collation:

```bash
initdb --encoding=UTF8 --licale-provider=libc --locale=POSIX datadir
```

Comment: Yup. Thanks. That's the problem. If I do ```--locale=potatoes``` I get (as I'd expect) an error. If I do ```--icu-locale=potatoes``` it (for some reason) doesn't error, it just appears to create the DB successfully (but wrongly).

Comment: ICU accepts the name without error, so PostgreSQL cannot tell.